# How to fix componentDidUpdate sending request over and over again

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new in react and redux. I have a table called "units". From there I want to fetch all the data and show the data immediately after one row added. That's why I call the this.props.fetchProductUnit(); in the componentDidUpdate(). But the problem is it fall into an infinite loop. It is sending the request over and over again. So what should be the stopping condition there.

action

```
export const fetchProductUnit = () => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        let units=[];
        await Axios.get('http://localhost:4000/getUnit').then(response => {
            dispatch({ type : 'FETCH_UNITS', payload: response.data})
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })

    }
}
```

main component

```
componentDidUpdate() {
        this.props.fetchProductUnit();    
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        //this.getUnitsHandler();
        this.props.fetchProductUnit();
    }

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
    return {
        units: state.units
    }
}


  return (
            <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <div className="card">
                    <div className="card-header bg-dark text-white">
                        <h4 className="d-inline">Product Unit Settings</h4>
                        <button className="d-inline btn btn-success btn-sm float-right" data-toggle="modal"
                            data-target="#addUnitModal">
                            <i className="material-icons">add</i>
                        </button>
                        <AddUnit changeInput={this.inuptChangeHandler}
                            addUnit={this.postUnitHandler}
                            state={this.state.unitName} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <Units units={this.props.units}
                            deleteUnit={this.deleteUnitHandler}
                            update={this.updateUnitHandler} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
    return {
        units: state.units
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, { 
    fetchProductUnit
})(ProductUnit);
```

I want componendDidMount to fetch the data initially and after each addition of data componentDidUpdate will fetch the data again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call your `fetchProductUnit` in two cases:

1. In `componentDidMount` for initial fetch
2. After you've added new product unit - since you haven't posted whole code, I guess it's `postUnitHandler` method (basically just after POST insert has finished, call `fetchProductUnit` again)

Answer (score 0):

You should call `fetchProductUnit` manually when the data gets updated, for example as a callback to the method that adds a product row, instead of having it in `componentDidUpdate`.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution #1**

If you make use of componentDidUpdate, you have to check the incoming props/state that determines the update and put a conditional on it:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  // This conditional assure that function is triggered only when relative data changes
  if (this.props.unit !== prevProps.unit) {
      this.props.fetchProductUnit();
  }
}
```

**Solution #2**

You can call your method in the end of this.postUnitHandler, maybe in the callback of the `setState()` that probably occurs in that method.

Comment: but in this case both are returning the same data

Comment: what are returning the same data ? If same data are incoming no update should occurr, because the response of the xhr will be the same